# Why isn't pangram missing letter function returning anything?

Tags: c++, string, compare

I have to write a function that takes a string and returns all the missing letters in the string.  The function below seemed simple enough but it's not returning anything. Any hints?

```
string getMissingLetters(const string& sentence)
{
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string sent = sentence;
    transform(sent.begin(), sent.end(), sent.begin(), ::tolower);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sent.size(); i++)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < alphabet.size(); j++)
        {
            if(sent[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                alphabet.erase(i);
                j--;
            }
        }
    return alphabet;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you're passing by reference, but the first thing you do is make a copy.  It would be easier and more flexible to pass by value instead.

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* your code? You code contains a very classic and a very basic bug. Bugs are found by debugging your code. SO is not intended as a "debug it for me" community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

alphabet.erase(j,1);

to erase a single character at position j.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Plus i replaced j-- with break.

Answer (score 0):

`alphabet.erase(i)` should probably be `alphabet.erase(j)`

Look at what your current code does:

The outer loop examines the first letter of the sentence, then, if the inner loop finds it in the alphabet, it removes "a" from the alphabet. If it's still in the alphabet, it removes "b", and so on. If there's a "z" in your sentence, the entire alphabet will always be removed.